# How can you dynamically test for Self types and unrelated types

Tags: reflection, swift

In Swift I can write:

```
func id(_: Any) -> Int? {
    return nil
}
func id<T: Hashable>(hashable: T) -> Int? { // Weird, what's T needed for? Why not "func id(hashable: Hashable) -> Int? {"?
    return hashable.hashValue
}
func id(object: AnyObject) -> Int? {
    return reflect(object).objectIdentifier?.hashValue
}
```

However the above selects the id function to call based on the static (declared) type of the argument. I really wanted the dynamic version that used the actual runtime type, i.e. I really want:

```
func dynamicId(anything: Any) -> Int? {
    switch anything {
    case let hashable as Hashable:
        return hashable.hashValue
    case let object as AnyObject:
        return reflect(object).objectIdentifier?.hashValue
    }
    return nil
}
```

The problem is that the two 'case let ... as ...:' lines are rejected by the compiler. Both lines have the error:

- Downcast from 'Any' to unrelated type ...

In addition the first line has the error:

- Protocol 'Hashable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

These errors seem a little constraining to me because I am testing for a type rather than unconditionally casting to a type.

Any hints how I might write this?

Thanks in advance, -- Howard.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_426),

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute.

`Hashable` and `AnyObject` are not @objc protocols, so what you're trying to do seems to not be supported.

Comment: Yes, the dynamic capabilities are limited at the moment. I was hoping someone had a good idea how to do this :)

Comment: Oops, meant to say that AnyObject is attributed with @objc but it is still rejected :(. But totally agree that Hashable was never going to work. The post was to pick the collective brains to see if I missed something.